# Unmarshalling exception while receiving response from soap

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap-client, unmarshalling

My xml soap response looks like mentioned below and I additionally I see unmarshalling exception org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault")

```
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <env:Header>
        <wsa:Action>process***</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
            <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
                <instra:tracking.ecid
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">0f285c
                </instra:tracking.ecid>
                <instra:tracking.FlowEventId
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">110
                </instra:tracking.FlowEventId>
                <instra:tracking.FlowId
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">233
                </instra:tracking.FlowId>
                <instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">0000OawEgND
                </instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId>
                <instra:tracking.quiescing.SCAEntityId
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">90
                </instra:tracking.quiescing.SCAEntityId>
            </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:FaultTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:FaultTo>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ResponseSolution
            xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/10"
            xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/REQ2DELPHI"
            xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Delphi_Requisition_OAG"
            xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
            xmlns:ns3="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9"
            xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/10"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            <tns:DataArea>
                <tns:Respond>
                    <tns:Area>
                        <tns:Receiver>
                            <tns:ID>***</tns:ID>
                            <tns:Conent>****</tns:Conent>
                        </tns:Receiver>
                    </tns:Area>
                </tns:Respond>
            </tns:DataArea>
        </ResponseSolution>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Here is my webserviceConfig

public class WebServiceConfig {

```
private String username;
private String password;


@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPaths("****ition", "*****ion");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public SoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    return new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
}

@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername(username);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(password);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType(WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    securityInterceptor.setValidationActions(WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(callbackHandler());
    return securityInterceptor;
}
@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller,
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor) {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
     webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[] { securityInterceptor });

    return webServiceTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CallbackHandler callbackHandler() {
    return callbacks -> {
        for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
            if (callback instanceof WSPasswordCallback) {
                WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callback;
                if (username.equals(pc.getIdentifier())) {
                    pc.setPassword(password);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Let me know what additional changes I need to make to fix the issue